# Vue3 impossible to use typescript variable inside scss

Tags: html, typescript, sass, vuejs3

I have a component with a template like this:

```
<template>
  ...
    <ul class="circle-container">
      <li v-for="img in images" :key="img">
        <img :src="img" alt="..." />
      </li>
    </ul>
  ...
</template>
```

The typescript code is the following:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Skills",
  setup() {
    const images = [
      ...
    ];

    const myCount = ref({
      nbItems: 8,
    });

    return { images, myCount };
  },
});
</script>
```

Now inside my scss code, I'm having a mixin defined somewhere else and this mixin takes parameters.
I would like to pass myCount as first parameter:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "../scss/main.scss";

.circle-container {
  @include on-circle(
    $item-count: v-bind("myCount.nbItems"),
    $circle-size: 20em,
    $item-size: 6em
  );
  ...
}

...
</style>
```

When I do this I get the following error:

Syntax Error: SassError: v-bind("myCount.nbItems") is not a number.

However, if I use the v-bind variable for a direct css attribute like:

```
p {
  font-size: v-bind("myCount.nbItems")
}
```

It works like a charm...

I don't get why it won't work when I try to use it as mixin parameter, can someone help?

Comment: sass generates css when it is compiled, meaning it can't see any runtime variables the html in vue is dynamically generated and patched to the dom.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to resolve my problem with an alternative way.
The mixin was meant to generate an dynamic animation that makes images orbit through a circular path and required the circle diameter (I wanted it to be dynamic for shrinking the circle size when the navigator page was resized).

Instead of trying to pass the variable to sass, I used the Animation Web Api which allows to define keyframes animation and animate Html elements from typescript.